# Am I allowed to sell software made with PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

So basically I want to create some software using the PyQt library, but do I have to make it open-source because it's under some kind of license? For the purpose of my software, making it open-source defeats the whole purpose of charging money for it.

Comment: Similar question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339723/can-i-sell-my-pyqt4-app-without-having-a-pyqt-license).

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. The license is extremely expensive though. I've gone to WxPython now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in order to produce non-open source software in PyQt5 you will need to buy a license.  See last question on https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/commercial/license-faq